# How to remove multiple, repeating ranges of lines from a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, unix, sed

I am working with a csv file which is an output from a Gas chromatograph data analyzer so I can only manipulate what is provided. I need to remove lines that are unnecessary from the csv file or keep only the necessary lines. There are 960 lines in the actual file.

The 1st 8 lines in the file look like this

```
[Line 1]  Remove
[Line 2]  Remove
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 4]  Remove
[Line 5]  Remove
[Line 6]  Remove
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
```

The pattern of line ranges I want to keep/remove continues for hundreds of lines, so here is the next 8 lines as an example.

```
[Line 9]   Remove
[Line 10]  Remove
[Line 11]  Keep
[Line 12]  Remove
[Line 13]  Remove
[Line 14]  Remove
[Line 15]  Keep
[Line 16]  Keep
```

There are no string patterns that discern these lines only the line numbers themselves. I would like to avoid having to calculate the ranges from hundreds of lines and put them all in sed like the script shown below which only cuts the desired number of lines for the first 8 lines only.

```
    sed '1,2d; 4,6d' test.csv >> cut_test.csv
```

I am hoping for the following:

```
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
[Line 11] Keep
[Line 15] Keep
[Line 16] Keep
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the line numbers to keep are following the exact pattern (repeating every 8 lines) that you have provided in your explanation, you can use the following GNU sed command:

```
$ sed '1~8d;2~8d;4~8d;5~8d;6~8d;' input.csv 
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
[Line 11]  Keep
[Line 15]  Keep
[Line 16]  Keep
```

and redirect it to a new file or user `-i.back` to change the file in-place.

**Explanation:**

- `1~8d` will execute the `d` command on the 1st line, 9th line,...
- `2~8d` will execute the `d` command on the 2nd line, 10th line,...

**input.csv:**

```
$ cat input.csv 
[Line 1]  Remove
[Line 2]  Remove
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 4]  Remove
[Line 5]  Remove
[Line 6]  Remove
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
[Line 9]   Remove
[Line 10]  Remove
[Line 11]  Keep
[Line 12]  Remove
[Line 13]  Remove
[Line 14]  Remove
[Line 15]  Keep
[Line 16]  Keep
```

You can even simplify the command by regrouping everything in the following way (that is close to your command):

```
$ sed '1~8,2~8d;4~8,6~8d;' input.csv 
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
[Line 11]  Keep
[Line 15]  Keep
[Line 16]  Keep
```

As mentioned by [Thor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331399/thor) you can reduce the command if, instead of deleting the lines you want to remove, you just print the lines you want to keep:

```
$ sed -n '3~8p;7~8,8~8p;' input.csv
[Line 3]  Keep
[Line 7]  Keep
[Line 8]  Keep
[Line 11]  Keep
[Line 15]  Keep
[Line 16]  Keep
```

Comment: Selecting is shorter, i.e. run with `-n` and this script `3~8p; 7~8p; 8~8p`

Comment: @Thor: You are completely right! Thank you, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you Thor and Allen, I love this solution. There are only two issues: 1) I needed to download the GNU sed (gsed) to use ~, but that was easy using macports, 2) In the actual file the pattern is 60 lines, so I want to keep line 4, and lines 20-60. Given that, writing it out ends up being a bit of a slog, but I should have mentioned that in the question. Since the number of lines I want to remove is actually less with the real file I ended up with the following code and it worked like a charm:

Comment: gsed '1~60d;2~60d;3~60d;5~60d;6~60d;7~60d;8~60d;9~60d;10~60d;11~60d;12~60d;13~60d;14~60d;15~60d;16~60d;17~60d;18~60d;19~60d' Test_2.csv > Cut.csv

Comment: @amwalker: You could have `sed` generate the script in either case, e.g.: `( echo 4; seq 20 60) | sed 's/$/~60p/' | sed -nf - infile`

Answer (score 3):

The Python approach is just

```
import sys
for i,l in enumerate(sys.stdin):
  if i%8 in (2,6,7): print(l)  # 0-based
```

Answer (score 1):

The sed solution is elegant, but as you also tagged Python, here's an equivalent solution in that language. It should scale to enormous files if it ever becomes necessary, because it never reads the entire file at once (which I believe is true of the sed solution too):

```
import itertools

with open('input.csv', 'r') as in_file:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines(entry for entry, keep in zip(in_file.readlines(), itertools.cycle([False, False, True, False, False, False, True, True])) if keep)
```

Comment: Ah sorry, left in from an incomplete snippet that didn't do file handling. It's just in_file.readlines(). Edited. That also obviates the need for "+ '\n'", again edited.

Comment: That said, this solution is mostly inferior to yours anyway. I guess I just think in convoluted ways these days.

Comment: `readlines` is eager (and so is `zip` in Python 2), which is why I just used the file object.  But the `itertools.cycle` does let you do things like `[0]*12+[1]*34+[0]`, like the edited question might want.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:

Default action in `awk` for a match is printing the line:
    awk 'NR%8~/3|7|0/' input.csv

**Long answer**, inspired by the comments of @kvantour

```
awk 'NR%8~/3|7|0/' input.csv
# or shorter (when module < 10)
awk 'NR%8~/[037]/' input.csv
```

When you need  modulo > 9, you need to match the complete line with the `^$` markers. With modulo 25 and lines 3,7,8,11,14,22 you can use

```
awk 'NR%25~/^[3|7|0|11|14|22]$/' input.csv
# or shorter
awk 'NR%25~/^[037]|1[14]|22$/' input.csv
```

This becomes harder to read for more values. An alternative is

```
# Original case
awk 'BEGIN {a[3];a[7];a[0]} NR%8 in a' input.csv 
# 3,7,8,11,14,22
awk 'BEGIN {a[3];a[7];a[8];a[11];a[14];a[22];} NR%25 in a' input.csv
```

Pulling the numbers out:

```
# Original case
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} FNR%8 in a' <(printf "%s\n" 3 7 0) input.csv 
# 3,7,8,11,14,22
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0];next} FNR%25 in a' <(printf "%s\n" 3 7 8 11 14 22) input.csv
```

Comment: Similar but probably slightly faster: `awk '"037"~(NR%8)'` Be aware that this trick only works if the modulo is always below 10

Comment: A shorter version for yours would be: `awk 'NR%8~/[037]/'` If the modulo is for example 19, you would have to do things like `awk 'NR%19~/^([037]|10|16)$/'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 'n;n;p;n;n;n;n;p;n;p' file
```

Does as it says on the tin.

Better (already mentioned by Thor):

```
sed -n '3~8p;7~8,+1p' file
```